# FreeRadius - SQL MAC Address Verification in Users file

Tags: freeradius

I am attempting to set up freeradius in the following way:

User: jsmith

- Group: technology
  User: msmith
- Group: hs-teachers

Each user is permitted to use a school-owned device and a BYOD device.

If jsmith connects to the network using a school-owned device, I want freeradius to check a sql table for the existance of that device's mac address, verify it is there, and then pass the authentication to EAP. I then want the user's credentials to be verified, resulting in jsmith being placed in the school-owned technology group vlan of 5.

if jsmith connects to the network using a BYOD device, I want the mac address to be checked, and upon not finding it in the sql database, jsmith's credentials are used to put him in the byod technology vlan of 255.

Similar with msmith. Using school-owned devices should result in her being in the hs-teachers school-owned vlan, and a byod device should result in her bein in the byod hs-teachers vlan.

I spent a decent amount of time trying to get chatgpt to get me there, but this most recent solution keeps showing the error below:

```
# Instantiating module "files" from file /usr/local/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/filesreading pairlist file /usr/local/etc/raddb/mods-config/files/authorize/usr/local/etc/raddb/mods-config/files/authorize[4]: Parse error (reply) for entry DEFAULT: Expecting operatorFailed reading /usr/local/etc/raddb/mods-config/files/authorize/usr/local/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/files[9]: Instantiation failed for module "files"
```

I'm confused because it looks like the operator of >= is being used in the config I've included just below. It is likely that I've just been staring at this enough to not notice something stupid, but help would be greatly appreciated. If this isn't something that I'm even close to achieving with this configuration, then that would also be helpful to know.  I did notice the inconsistant use of COUNT(*), but I left it for sake of the example.

This is my users file, which pushes to the authorize file:

```
DEFAULT Auth-Type := Reject
DEFAULT Ldap-Group == "cn=technology,ou=Groups,dc=wftigers,dc=org"
if ("%{sql:SELECT COUNT(*) '_snipeit_mac_address_1' FROM 'assets' WHERE '_snipeit_mac_address_1' = '%{Calling-Station-Id}'}" >= 1) {
Tunnel-Type = VLAN,
Tunnel-Medium-Type = IEEE-802,
Tunnel-Private-Group-Id = 5, # School-owned technology VLAN
Fall-Through = Yes
}
else {
Tunnel-Type = VLAN,
Tunnel-Medium-Type = IEEE-802,
Tunnel-Private-Group-Id = 255, # BYOD technology VLAN
Fall-Through = Yes
}
DEFAULT Ldap-Group == "cn=hs-teacher,ou=Groups,dc=wftigers,dc=org"
if ("%{sql:SELECT _snipeit_mac_address_1 FROM assets WHERE _snipeit_mac_address_1 = '%{Calling-Station-Id}'}" > 0) {
Tunnel-Type = VLAN,
Tunnel-Medium-Type = IEEE-802,
Tunnel-Private-Group-Id = 6, # School-owned hs-teacher VLAN
Fall-Through = Yes
}
else {
Tunnel-Type = VLAN,
Tunnel-Medium-Type = IEEE-802,
Tunnel-Private-Group-Id = 12, # BYOD hs-teacher VLAN
Fall-Through = Yes
}
DEFAULT Tunnel-Type = VLAN,
Tunnel-Medium-Type = IEEE-802,
Tunnel-Private-Group-Id = 666 # Default VLAN for other cases
```

I just finished up a little more time editing, and came up with the following, but the error now states that line 3 (the first DEFAULT Ldap...) is expecting an end of line or a comma.

```
DEFAULT Auth-Type := Reject

DEFAULT Ldap-Group == "cn=technology,ou=Groups,dc=wftigers,dc=org" {
if ("%{sql:SELECT COUNT(*) FROM assets WHERE _snipeit_mac_address_1 = '%{Calling-Station-Id}'}" >= 1) {
Tunnel-Type = VLAN,
Tunnel-Medium-Type = IEEE-802,
Tunnel-Private-Group-Id = 5, # School-owned technology VLAN
Fall-Through = Yes
}
else {
Tunnel-Type = VLAN,
Tunnel-Medium-Type = IEEE-802,
Tunnel-Private-Group-Id = 255, # BYOD technology VLAN
Fall-Through = Yes
}
}
DEFAULT Ldap-Group == "cn=hs-teacher,ou=Groups,dc=wftigers,dc=org" {
if ("%{sql:SELECT COUNT(*) FROM assets WHERE _snipeit_mac_address_1 = '%{Calling-Station-Id}'}" >= 1) {
Tunnel-Type = VLAN,
Tunnel-Medium-Type = IEEE-802,
Tunnel-Private-Group-Id = 6, # School-owned hs-teacher VLAN
Fall-Through = Yes
}
else {
Tunnel-Type = VLAN,
Tunnel-Medium-Type = IEEE-802,
Tunnel-Private-Group-Id = 12, # BYOD hs-teacher VLAN
Fall-Through = Yes
}
}
DEFAULT Tunnel-Type = VLAN,
Tunnel-Medium-Type = IEEE-802,
Tunnel-Private-Group-Id = 666 # Default VLAN for other cases
```